# How to add custom action set to my custom perspective in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

Is there a way to define custom action set that will be visible only when i switch to my custom perspective?

```
    extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
<perspectiveExtension 
            targetID="com.mycustom.ui.perspective.ApplicationPerspective">              
            <actionSet id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpointActionSet"/> 
            <actionSet id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchActionSet"/>
            <actionSet  id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugActionSet"/>
            <actionSet
                  id="org.eclipse.mycustom.actionSet">
            </actionSet>
           <hiddenToolBarItem id="org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.DebugDropDownAction"/>        
        </perspectiveExtension> 
  </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
      <actionSet
         label="Sample Action Set"
         visible="false"
         id="org.eclipse.mycustom.actionSet">
           <action
                label="My toolbar item"
                class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.MYCustomClass"
                id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.customaction">
            </action>
      </actionSet>
   </extension>
```

Comment: Sure. Just look at how EGit does it, for example.

Comment: ahh i want to do with plugin.xml in my current project set up like that.. I saw some extension way but it did not fully work since actionSet id not okay. @howlger

Comment: I can't imagine what you want that EGit doesn't do. Please show sample code and describe the actual vs. the expected behavior.

Comment: You use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point for this. If you have tried this and had problems show us what you did.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 i have edit my question. Please have a look. Thank you

Comment: Simply i have one toolbar item custom one the one i have developed. I would like to show that item only when i switch to custom perspective. @greg-449

Comment: So you use the `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` extension point to define the actiion set (it is deprecated but for this you have to use it).

Comment: okay i have edit again and tried to use like this but did not work actually.. Do u think i am missing something? @greg-449

Comment: You probably need to reset the perspective to get it to pick up the new extensions.

Comment: no it does not visible unfortunately.. @greg-449

Comment: you have not specified a `menubarPath` or a `toolbarPath`  so the action won't be visible anywhere.